# Pygame top down shooter firing bullets

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a top down shooter in pygame and am having trouble getting bullets to fire. I'm using a class for the bullets, I'll show what I think is the relevant code.

This is what I do after the mouse button is clicked:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        bullet_vel=[0,0]
        fired_pos=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        player.fired=True
        bullet_pos_from_player=[0,0]


        bullet_pos_from_player[0]=fired_pos[0]-player.rect[0]
        bullet_pos_from_player[1]=fired_pos[1]-player.rect[1]
        bulletdistance=math.sqrt(abs((bullet_pos_from_player[0])^2) + abs((bullet_pos_from_player[1])^2))
        bullet_vel[0]=bullet_pos_from_player[0]/bulletdistance
        bullet_vel[1]=bullet_pos_from_player[1]/bulletdistance

        print bullet_vel[0], bullet_vel[1]

        bulletgroup.add(bullet((bullet_vel)))
```

and here is my class for the bullet:

```
class bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, bullet_vel):
    super(bullet,self).__init__()
    self.pos=player.draw_pos
    self.image=pygame.transform.rotate(bullet_image, player.angle)
    self.vel=bullet_vel


def update(self):
    self.pos[0]=self.pos[0]+self.vel[0]
    self.pos[1]=self.pos[1]+self.vel[1]
    screen.blit(self.image, self.pos)
```

Hope someone can help out,

thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is likely the typo in the line:

```
pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init(self)
```

The `__init__` function in python is special, and should be called as such. That being said, your code would be cleaner and you could avoid these issues if you used [new-style class inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694371/how-do-i-initialize-the-base-super-class-in-python):

```
class bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, bullet_vel):
        super(bullet, self).__init__()
....
```

Another fairly egregious error is in these lines:

```
    bullet_vel[0]=math.ceil(math.sinh(bullet_angle)*bulletspeed)
    bullet_vel[1]=math.ceil(math.cosh(bullet_angle)*bulletspeed)
```

The problems are:

1. `sinh` and `cosh` are hyperbolic functions, and not what you want. You're probably looking for the regular `sin` and `cos` functions.
2. `cos` corresponds to the x-axis, and `sin` corresponds to the y-axis. You have them reversed.
3. There is no need to take the cieling of them... python does a good job of handling floating point. If you need them to be integers for the sake of pygame's libraries, then it's better to call `int()` on them once you need to.
4. The `sin` and `cos` functions [take arguments in radians](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#trigonometric-functions)

Finally, you're not saving the value of your bullet_vel variable in your bullet's `__init__` function. Hence, if you ever do reach the bullet's `update` call, then it will raise an error. You will need to add something like

```
self.vel = bullet_vel
```

to the `__init__` function and call `self.pos.move(self.vel)` in the bullet's `update` function.

Comment: Thank you, you're right in that the first one was a simple typo, I don't know how I managed to miss that. I'll definitely have a good look at everything and try to fix up the code with what you've said when I have time.

thank you,